# I try this and don't know how to open the first video. This code opens the search in the browser

Tags: python-3.x

```
import webbrowser

def findYT(search):
   words = search.split()

   link = "http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query="

   for i in words:
      link += i + "+"

   time.sleep(1)
   webbrowser.open_new(link[:-1])
```

Comment: how are you calling ```findYT()```?

Comment: findYT('song name')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to get thing up and running, then you have to make some changes according to the code, which I am about to show you.

**YOUR CODE FLAWS**

1. Your code doesn't follow the standards of YouTube searching
2. YouTube uses encoded strings, you cannot just simply pass the search item
3. You must take a word for search and pass it to the query

**DISCLAIMER**

I don't use the `webbrowser` module, but I can give you the standard output, which you can use to open up the result on your browser.

If you didn't understand the above, then see the code instead:

```
# urllib is used to encode the string
# re is used for finding the item as per our requirements
import urllib
import re 

def findYT(search):
    # first rule is in order to pass the data to the YouTube
    # search query, it has to be in encoded format
    # for example, god's country => god%26s%20country
    encoded_query = urllib.quote(search)
    print(encoded_query) #printing to check what is the output
    
    # YouTube searches the item in the format
    # https://youtube.com/results?search_query='your_encoded_string'
    # it opens up the url, and fetches all the data of the result
    html_content = urllib.urlopen("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + encoded_query)

    # If we can click on any of the results via browser, we always see the url 
    # as https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={11_length_code}
    # so now from all the results, we fetch the result data's this 11 length code
    # result = [code1, code2, code3, code4]
    search_results = re.findall(r'watch\?v=(.{11})', html_content.read().decode('utf-8'))
    
    #this is the result you want, and you can now use it with your webbrowser
    my_top_result = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + search_results[0]
    # so the search_results[0] will have the first result from the list of the results
    print(my_top_result)


# calling your method with one search result that is god's country
# you can use input() if raw_input() doesn't work out for you
search_item = raw_input('Enter any video name: ')
findYT(search_item)
```

**FOR PYTHON 3.x:** If you land yourself facing this problem of `Attribute Error` in `quote()` and `urlopen()`, then do this, and follow the above code. You will be good to go :)

```
# For Python3.x quote()
urllib.quote() => urllib.parse.quote()

# For Python3.x urlopen()
urllib.urlopen() => urllib.request.urlopen()
```

**OUTPUT**

```
>>> Enter any video name: god's country
>>> god%27s%20country
>>> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZEWGyyLiqY4
```

If you open the url, which you've got from your Chrome/Safari/Firefox, it will open the video.

Also, if you just type in God's country in your YouTube result, the first result you will get is the one, for which we have the final url. You can open the first video, and match the url, with our my_top_result.

**SUGGESTION**

You can also put a check, if the search_results = [], then generate an output saying, **No Results Found**.

Comment: Hey @AndrewSantos, if that helped you then you can mark the answer as correct by **checking the tick mark beside my answer, which will turn green as you do so**, also, you can upvote the answer **which you can do by clicking on the top arrow above number 0, which will increment the value of the votes**. This is how we follow the standards of StackOverFlow Thanks :)

Comment: Oh It appeared an error AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'quote'

Comment: @AndrewSantos It is because, I have the code for `Python2.x` and this is kinda `Python3.x`, so do one thing, do this => `urllib.parse.urlencode()` for `urlib.quote()`, and `urllib.request.urlopen()` for `urllib.urlopen()`. Do that and let me know

Comment: It worked but i have change urllib.parse.urlencode() to  urllib.parse.quote():))